# Can queries on views be fully tested?

Tags: sql, unit-testing, sql-view

So I have a query:

```
select
  c.STRING,
  a.STRING,
  b.STRING,
  b.STRING3,
  a.STRING2,
from TABLE_A a,
  VIEW_B b,
  TABLE_C c
where b.STRING2 = a.STRING2
  and a.INT = #value#
  and c.INT = a.INT
  and c.STRING IN ('string1', 'string2')
```

VIEW_B is a view and TABLE_A and TABLE_C are normal tables. I am trying to unit test this query. The way I saw it was that because it is a select, I need to make some dummy data, insert it into the tables, and then run the above query and make sure it returns the same data I put in. However, VIEW_B is a view, and cannot be inserted into. So I need to get some real data from VIEW_B and its corresponding data in the other 2 tables. However, by that point I'm just running the same query, plus I have to grab an a.INT. So my conclusion is that if I have a query that uses views, it can't be fully tested.

Is this true? Regardless, what is the best way to test this query?

Keep in mind that this is a work project and that I can't change the schema of the tables or the query itself, and I have to run my tests against the actual database.

Comment: actually you might be able to insert into the view, depends on what it is, and the tables it depends on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just provide sample data for whatever tables make up VIEW_B?

Alternatively, replace "VIEW_B" with an inline entity declaration:

(I used oracle-specific DUAL dummy table, but use whatever works for you)

```
select
  c.STRING,
  a.STRING,
  b.STRING,
  b.STRING3,
  a.STRING2
from TABLE_A a,
  (select 'blah' string, 123 INT from dual) b,
  TABLE_C c
where b.STRING2 = a.STRING2
  and a.INT = #value#
  and c.INT = a.INT
  and c.STRING IN ('string1', 'string2')
```

Comment: The view queries from 4 other tables, 2 of which are also views :P, and it's pretty complicated... However I just remembered that my boss said he wanted us to stop using the views because we are moving away from them, so I'll just have to suck it up. But thanks! That was actually helpful, and I did not know you could even declare inline entities.

Comment: Note sure what version of oracle you're using, but look up the "WITH" declaration to define custom entities just for that query... it's great for testing out queries.

Comment: My workplace actually uses Sybase ASE, not Oracle, though we are moving toward Oracle.